# Expect is not recognizing $expect_out(buffer) or $expect_out(0,string)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, expect

I have Ubuntu 9.10 (and cannot change it in the near future due to testing) with expect5.45. 
Expect is working, but I have (at least) two issues. 
The first is that expect does not seem to be matching the string "password:". 
On my machine, the manual interaction appears as below:

```
root@Monkey2:~# rlogin $remoteAddress -l root
root@nn.nn.nnn.nnn's password: 
Linux systest-desktop 2.6.31-22-generic #70-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 1 23:51:13 UTC 2010 i686

To access official Ubuntu documentation, please visit:
http://help.ubuntu.com/

72 packages can be updated.
70 updates are security updates.

Last login: Mon Jun 20 13:40:22 2011 from monkey2.local
root@systest-desktop:~#
```

The contents of the script is as follows:

> ```
> #!/usr/local/bin/expect -f
>
> ##  Connect to a neighboring linux box.
> spawn ssh nn.nn.nnn.nnn -l root
>
> expect "password:\n"
>
> send "mypassword\n"
>
> send "$expect_out(0,string)"
> ```

The script gets and displays the line requesting the password but times out. 
I've tried using "password:", "password: ", "password:\r" and password:*" but none seem to match.

---

The second issue is that the expect_out variable is not recognized and I get the following error when I run the script (whose name is 'this' and only has 11 lines!):

> can't read "expect_out(0,string)": no such variable
>       while executing
>   "send "$expect_out(0,string)""
>       (file "this" line 18)

Answer (score 8):

First thing to do when debugging expect programs is to add this line near the top:

```
exp_internal 1
```

That turns on (verbose) debugging output that shows what expect has seen from the spawned program, and how it matches your expect patterns.

Typically, one does something like this:

```
expect -re {password: $}
send -- "the_password\r"
```

You need to send a `\r` (a carriage return) instead of `\n`.

Comment: Thank you Glenn. Magically, expect_out() is working, and with your suggestions, I'm getting matches. Thank you for your help! (BTW, I do have "Exploring Expect" by Don Libes, but I'm just into chapter 4 now. I'll need to look up the -- option for send ..

Comment: @Mike, good job getting "the" book. The "--" option is to explicitly signal the end of options for the command just in case the string you want to send begins with a hyphen. It's a good habit to get into, and will save your butt if you're dealing with user input and `send -- $user_input\r`

Comment: Thanks, @glennjackman! Is this the book you guys are referring to: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920903.do

Comment: This answer does not answer the second (part of the) question.